# R markdown to MS Word: keep paragraphs together

Tags: r, ms-word, markdown

I am creating a report in MS Word and am using a RMarkdown document. I have managed to use a `reference.docx` file where I adjusted the styles of titles, headers, text, and figure captions to my need. Now I would like to make sure some lines, paragraphs and pictures are kept together on the same page. Is there a way to do this?

Here's my sample code

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  word_document: 
    reference_docx: reference.docx
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
Here is some text.


### I Use This as Figure Caption Above the Figure
(Index, 2015=100, seasonally adjusted series)

![Source: World Bank](https://previews.123rf.com/images/lovjane/lovjane1610/lovjane161000009/64921112-hand-drawn-sun-with-face-and-eyes-alchemy-medieval-occult-mystic-symbol-of-sun-vector-illustration-.jpg){ width=10cm }

The last 3 lines are the ones I would like to be kept together in my MS-Word output file, i.e. Caption+(Comment)+Figure.
````

Comment: If they fit into one page, maybe you could wrap them with `\newpage` or `\pagebreak`.

Comment: From experience, you are going to struggle to fine tune the output of word documents. Normally it is just easier to tailor the output as you require.

Answer (score 2):

You can include certain properties in your style definitions - that's the best way. You'll want to test this in the Word environment to get a feel for how these work as they can be confusing.

1. For all paragraphs that should stay together on the same page (as long as the total length does not exceed the space available on the page):

   - Paragraph dialog box (P-dlg)/Line and Page Breaks tab (LPB-tab)/`Keep with Next`
   - In the Word object model corresponds to: `Paragraph.KeepWithNext = true/false`
2. For the last paragraph in this group, make sure to *remove* this property. This means a separate style for the last paragraph!
3. To force lines to stay together:

   - P-dlg/LPB-tab/`Keep lines together`
   - In the Word object model corresponds to: `Paragraph.KeepTogether = true/false`

The same commands will apply to any pictures formatted in-line with the text. You may want to define separate styles for pictures if they need special alignment or spacing.

For pictures with text-wrap formatting the trick to keeping them together with specific text is to *lock the anchor* to the Range of that text. This cannot be part of a style, however.